# Autohotkey left click (or right) on screen triggered via hotkey not working

Tags: autohotkey

Hy Guys,

I am running **Autohotkey v1.1.32.00** (if that matters) and trying to do a Left click when hotkey `ctrl + alt + m` is pressed irrespective of the window or program basically any part of the screen where current mouse position is. The main purpose is to set focus to the window or part of the window via hotkey press then manually left click, basically do a left mouse click whenever hotkey is pressed. But its not working.

**Not Working**

```
^!m::
  MouseClick, Left
return
```

However, what works is when the `#IfWinActive ahk_exe my_program.exe` condition is used (as shown):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
^!m::
  MouseClick, Left
return
```

The problem with above is it only works for chrome.exe, I want it to work irrespective of the program running. Basically left click wherever the mouse position on screen is.

I even tried the suggestion in following question, i.e to create a new script file and run that script file, but that didn't work

[Autohotkey right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067727/autohotkey-right-click?rq=1)

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#InstallMouseHook
!^m::
Send, {LButton} ; OR {RButton} as you desire.
/*
OR alternatively it might be just too fast to be recognized
Send, {LButton down}
Sleep 300
Send, {LButton up}
*/
Return
```

Comment: If those don't work try using 'SendPlay' command instead.